# How can I treat a type that is essentially a tuple as a tuple in F#

Tags: syntax, f#, types, tuples

Ok, so let's say I have a type defined like so:

```
type Foo = 
    | Bar of (SomeType * SomeType * SomeType * SomeType)
    | ...(other defs)
```

so I have a Bar, that is basically a tuple of 4 SomeTypes.  I want to access individual members of the tuple.  I tried this:

let Bar (one, two, three, four) = someBar

But when I try to refer to one, or two later on in the function it says that "the value or constructor is not defined"  So it is not treating the assignment as expected.  What is the correct way to do this?

Also, if i try:

```
let one,two,three,four = someBar
```

It complains:
someBar was expected to have type 'a*'b*'c*'d but here has type Foo

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add another set of parentheses:

```
let (Bar(one,two,three,four)) = someBar
```

As Stephen points out, without the additional parens the compiler treats this line of code as the definition of a new function called `Bar`.  He is also right that pattern matching would probably be more appropriate if there are other cases in the discriminated union.

Comment: ah! adding parens flickered in my mind when I first saw this, but I didn't follow that path!

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
type Foo = 
    | Bar of (int * int * int * int)
    | Bar2 of string

let x = Bar(1,2,3,4)

let Bar(y1,y2,y3,y4) = x
```

the last let binding is interpreted as a function, `Bar : 'a * 'b * 'c * 'd -> Foo`. The function name is throwing you off, since it is the same as your union case, but it's the same as if you had defined `let some_func_takes_a_tuple_and_returns_x (y1,y2,y3,y4) = x`.

I think you may have to be a little more verbose:

```
let y1,y2,y3,y4 =
    match x with
    | Bar(y1,y2,y3,y4) -> y1,y2,y3,y4
```

Which is fair enough, since unlike tuple decomposition let bindings, decomposing `Bar` here is dangerous because the match is incomplete (`x` could actually be some other `Foo` case, like `Bar2`).

**Edit**

@kvb knows the secret to making this work as you expect!